# Active Model Serializer Pagination Link Not Generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, pagination, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm using the `master` Active Model [Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) and the [Pagination Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/fce856fc83771a42cce0dc9994ef449ebe9943c0/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md). This is may Pagination Serializer

```
# pagination collection serializer
class PaginationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer

  def initialize(object, options = {})
    meta_key = options[:meta_key] || :meta
    options[meta_key] ||= {}
    options[meta_key][:pagination] = {
      current_page: object.current_page,
      next_page: object.next_page,
      prev_page: object.prev_page,
      total_pages: object.total_pages,
      total_count: object.total_count,
      size: object.total_count
    }
    super(object, options)
  end

end
```

This is my rendering code.

```
render json: formulas, serializer: PaginationSerializer, each_serializer: FormulaSimpleSerializer
```

There no meta key on the result. This happens after upgrading from 0.10.0.RC3 to master. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
# my_app/app/application_controller.rb
...
def pagination_dict(object)
{
  current_page: object.current_page,
  next_page: object.next_page,
  prev_page: object.prev_page,
  total_pages: object.total_pages,
  total_count: object.total_count
}
end

# my_app/config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json
```

Render code:

```
render json: formulas, meta: pagination_dict(formulas)
```